# ordering query based on the which column containing searched value

Tags: mysql

so i have a table called products

products : title , tags , post , about , about2

when someone search for `xxx` in products i want products that contain `xxx` in their `tags` column to be on top after that `post` and `title` and `about` and `about2`

but when i run this query

```
    select id , title , tags , about , about2 , post from products where 

   `title` LIKE '%xxx%' ESCAPE '!' OR
   `tags` LIKE '%xxx%' ESCAPE '!' OR
   `post` LIKE '%xxx%' ESCAPE '!' OR
   `about` LIKE '%xxx%' ESCAPE '!' OR
   `about2` LIKE '%xxx%' ESCAPE '!' 

   ORDER BY FIELD( tags, post, title , about , about2)
```

here is the exported result ( each row's title been set to the name of columns that contains xxx )

```
(`id`, `title`, `tags`, `about`, `about2`, `post`) 
VALUES
(459, 'TAGS', 'xxx\n', '', '', ''),
(455, 'ABOUT 2', '', '', ' xxx', ''),
(456, 'ABOUT', '', ' xxx\n', '', ''),
(457, 'TITLE - xxx\n', '', '', '', ''),
(458, 'POST', '', '', '', 'xxx\n')
```

as you can see the ABOUTs are on the top and title , post are at the bottom

how can i sort the query to get tags on top and the rest as i said above ?

i've tried

```
ORDER BY (tags LIKE '%xxx%') ,
(post LIKE '%xxx%') ,
(title LIKE '%xxx%') ,
(about LIKE '%xxx%') ,
(about2 LIKE '%xxx%')
```

still i get about columns at the top !

Comment: Can you post the output you want and what did you get

Comment: there's no easy way to do this. it gets ugly quick, because the "hack" fix is to do something like `order by (title LIKE '%xxx%'), ...`

Comment: @geeksal i've added the result

Comment: @MarcB i've tried that !  i've edited my post

Comment: @progwin we can come with better results if you could post your schema along with data on http://sqlfiddle.com/